# Regex Between word

Tags: java, regex, database, cpu-word, between

I have strings

> Yangebup, Perth, Australia, Dated 2011-01-09
>
> Jakarta, Indonesia, Dated 2013-08-24

So I want to get the location name `Yangebup, Perth, Australia` and `Jakarta, Indonesia`

How can I get that location name with regex? I have tried to use this code `.+?,\bDated\b` but the result is Match not found.

I also tried with regexpal.com to test my regex, with this code `.+\bdated\b` I can get it, but i have to use the Case insensitive (i) and the result still nothing when I write it on my java program.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex pattern:

```
^(.*), Dated \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$

List<String> locations = new ArrayList<String>();
locations.add("Yangebup, Perth, Australia, Dated 2011-01-09");
locations.add("Jakarta, Indonesia, Dated 2011-01-09");

String pattern = "^(.*), Dated \\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

for (String location : locations) {
    Matcher m = r.matcher(location);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a location: " + m.group(1) );
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found a location: Yangebup, Perth, Australia
Found a location: Jakarta, Indonesia
```

Comment: That's a good pattern, but my problem is how to get the Jakarta, Indonesia also. actually I have about 7000 location like this, with more than 3 words inside. how to get all the location name?

Comment: This works for `Jakarta, Indonesia, Dated 2013-08-24` as well.  If, in addition to a regex, you want to separate city and country pairs, you can try using `String.split()`.

Comment: actually I can get the result, but I still confused how to get another location, if i have different string and I have to change all the matcher all times?